# How to force remove metadata of LVM?

Tags: partition, lvm

I have some HDDs with LVM metadata.

I didn't remove LVM partition gracefully.

I want to force to remove it.

Can I use `fdisk` repartition and `mkfs.ext4` to force to clean the metadata of LVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `fdisk` always asks if you want to remove existing filesystems first:

```
The device contains 'LVM2_member' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.
```

You can also use `wipefs -a /dev/sdxY` to remove all filesystem signatures from a device.

And if you want to be 100 % sure everything is gone, you can always use the biggest hammer available and write some zeroes to the device, all metadata should be in the first few megabytes of the disk sp `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdxY bs=1M count=100` will do the trick. But that's really not necessary and a big overkill.